# curl - Check content type before deciding what to do with payload

Tags: php, api, curl

I am working with an API that has a DownloadFile method.  Upon a successful request to the method, the response will have a content type of **application/octet-stream** and contain a file.  Upon an unsuccessful request to the method, the response will have a content type of **text/xml** and contain the appropriate error.

The files I am requesting are archives containing multiple photos and could get very large.  Therefore, I am using `CURLOPT_FILE` to write the payload directly to a file rather than storing it in memory.

My question is, is there any way to check the content type of the response and then decide what to do with the payload?  I only want to write the payload to a file if the content type is **application/octet-stream**.  Otherwise I just want to get the error from the XML response and return that to the user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send a [`HEAD` http](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) request before download and parse the response for the content-type field. For this, you will have to use `CURLOPT_NOBODY` and `CURLOPT_HEADER` options with maybe `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` so you get the full http HEAD sesction as a string from `curl_exec()`.